# Lenovo Legion "Conservation Mode" can't be disabled in Lenovo Vantage

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, lenovo-laptop, lenovo-vantage

I've been finding the "Conservation Mode" feature (*only charges to a max of 60% to preserve battery lifespan*) to be incredibly useful for me at school recently, but I just encountered an issue where the Lenovo Vantage software won't allow me to turn the mode off.

The notification center/tray menu just shows the red "input not allowed" cursor when I hover over the "Conservation Mode" icon and the toggle button in the Lenovo Vantage "Power" screen appears to switch over, but then doesn't have any effect and resets back to the on position when I come back to the "Power" screen. How can I turn the mode off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was trying to figure out how to solve the issue, I found this [article](https://www.thetechminute.com/plugged-in-not-charging-windows-10), which gave me the idea to try re-plugging the charger. This fixed the issue for me, and the two locations of the "Conservation Mode" toggle both function now.

I suppose disabling the "Conservation Mode" toggle only takes effect on the next charging initialization, as opposed to enabling it, which appears to take effect immediately, for some reason.